# MongoDB/Mongoose some of the model properties undefined in app.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on an Authentication/Session using Express, NodeJS, and MongoDB.

The Mongoose Schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, },
  password: { type: String, required: true, },
  SignUpDate: { type: { type: Date, default: Date.now } },
  LastLogin: { type: { type: Date, default: Date.now } },
  loggedin: { type: Boolean, required: false, },
  attempts: { type: Number },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The Signup form only takes username, email, password, but I would like to save sign update, last login, failed login attempts, etc.

In the controller.js file, I have the routes, this is the problematic one.

```
exports.register_post = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  let user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user) {
    req.session.error = "User already exists";
    return res.redirect("/register");
  }

  const hasdPsw = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

  user = new User({
    username,
    email,
    password: hasdPsw,
    SignUpDate,
    loggedin: true

  });

  await user.save();
  console.log(user)
  res.redirect("/login");
};
```

And in App.JS I have this

```
app.post("/register", appController.register_post);
```

If I only use username, email, and password in the Schema, it all works, saves to the database.

But as above, I get

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: SignUpDate is not
> defined"

if I submit the signup button on the /register route. Another question, if I want to get a timestamp with Mongoose, do I have to call `Date.now()` and where?

Or do I have to define and add/push the properties that are not user provided via Signup Post (   SignUpDate,LastLogin:,loggedin:,attempts ) to the Schema after the users sign up? I am new to using Mongoose, going through the docs and cant seem to find how to ad a timestamp.

A little update, if I comment out the SignUpDate,LastLogin variables in the post function, I get "Object, Object" in MongoDBcompass and the object is collapsible, it saved the values in the database but crashed the app. The change that was necessary was simply

```
   SignUpDate: { type: { type: Date, default: Date.now } },
   LastLogin: { type: { type: Date, default: Date.now } },
```

to

```
 SignUpDate: {
 type: Date, default: Date.now(),

},
LastLogin: {
type: Date, default: Date.now(),

}
```

[image]

This is how it looks in the database, and it gets saved and the app doesn't crash. but as soon I uncomment "SignUpDate" in the route function, I get the same undefined error again.

I can live with this, but would rather not. Besides, how do I convert "type: Date, default: Date.now()" to a nice out put like ""Sun May 10 2015 19:50:08 GMT-0600 (MDT)"? If I change it in the Schema, it don't work, if I change it in the route function, it will not let me chain the functions and I don't know where to declare the var for the nice formatted output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "SignUpDate":

```
const user = new User({
    username,
    email,
    password: hasdPsw,
    loggedin: true
  });
```

If you specified a default value, you don't need to specify it when you create new object.
If you want to accumulate the number of unsuccessful attempts, you need to get the users from the base, increase the counter by one and update it in the base. Smth like this:

```
let userAttempts = await User.findOne({ username });
await User.update({ username }, { $set: { attempts: userAttempts.attempts + 1 } });
```

Comment: I have just realized that it works anyway, as long it is defined in the Schema. Thanks for that. But how should I define it in the Schema to get a nicely formatted date? Dealing with the dates is rather important if I want to lock the accounts after 3 or 5 failed logins within { var time } .

Comment: @ptts use library 'date-fns', and your field in the scheme will look like this: date: {
    type: String,
    default: format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd'),
  },

Comment: I have just tried to to use a date input for date of birth, getting the same "dob" is undefined. Thanks will try that library